# Visual Basic : Extract and present Information from file

Tags: vb.net, extract

I am new to VB(.net) and currently struggling with a little program I want to build. I have a large text (12 MB) file from which I would like to extract data, aggregate/analyze them and show statistics and graphs about it. 
Basically the format of the text file is as followed:

```
trade=
{
    to="MEX"
    from="USA"
    trade_from=
    {
    0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000       }
    trade_to=
    {
    0.000 0.000 0.031 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000       }
    first="USA"
    second="MEX"

}
```

It is an example of one trade relationships between countries as presented in the  .txt.   The categories traded are presented by the 7 numbers (a,b,c,d,e,f,g). In this case, USA trades 1.0 f with 0.031c from Mex.

However, the file does not only include US relationships – so I have to check first, if USA is included either in to=””, or from=””. Furthermore, in many cases, there are more than one trade relationship between two countries.

The output table should look like the following:

*Trade relationships USA*

Traded Categories:       a  b   c   d   e   f   g

Total Trades with Mex           xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx

Total Trades with JPN         xx    xx  xx  xx  xx  xx  xx

So, basically, I have to sum all values per country traded with the USA (in this example) and provide a table with the total numbers per country per category.

Does anyone has an idea how to handle this?

Thanks very much for your help !!!

Ted

Comment: VB.NET or VB6: which one? It can’t be both.

Comment: Correct - it`s VB.NET - i forgot!

Comment: Define very large. Too big to want to fit the whole file in memory at once?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a streamreader to read files,or you should store the data in an XML file.An XML would be easier for the program to read, as you could use System.Xml.XmlReader for that.